# Altair chart save only the data to html that is actually part of the plot

Tags: python, altair

When creating a chart using `altair`, I like the fact that I can save it to `.html` containing all the data in the plot. However, also the columns of a `pd.DataFrame` that are not plotted are stored in the `.html` file.

I am in a situation, where my data frame has roughly 100 columns but only ~5 of them are part of the plot. Thus I'd like to be able to only save those columns in the plot that are actually used, decreasing the file size of the `.html` by a factor 20.

Here's an MWE:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

mwe_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": np.arange(10),
        "y": np.random.randn(10),
        "z": np.random.randn(10),
    }
)

chart = alt.Chart(mwe_df).mark_line().encode(
    x="x",
    y="y"
)
chart.save("mwe.html")
```

The resulting file `mwe.html` looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html

// I cut a lot of code away to show the important part

<body>
  <div id="vis"></div>
  <script>
    (function (vegaEmbed) {
        
        // I cut a lot of code away to show the important part

        "datasets": {
          "data-f268207ac55fefac2d4e472cf850ebe3": [{
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0.5499788508261615,
            "z": -1.477946005772743 // Don't want this here
          }, {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 0.6200551442726329,
            "z": 0.857375723129614 // Don't want this here
          }, {
            "x": 2,
            "y": 2.162997199610359,
            "z": 0.8528682789795423 // Don't want this here
          }, 

        // I cut a lot of code away to show the important part
</body>

</html>
```

I could of course only hand a subset of the data frame to `altair`, i.e. by calling `alt.Chart(mwe_df[["x","y"]])` but this seems a bit cumbersome.

Is there a way to tell `altair` to only save the relevant columns in the `.html`?

Answer (score 0):

I also think this would be a useful feature to have in Altair, but there are some considerations with implementing it. You can follow preliminary work and discussion in this PR https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/pull/2586. In addition of what is mentioned there, it is possible that something might be offered via VegaFusion (https://vegafusion.io/) in the future as it covers some of the same things as the altair_transform package.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Curious to see where this is going.